# wordpress logged in user contact form 7 values

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I would like to show autofill info for logged in user for my text value called company-name but I believe:

Available fields at the moment are: `user_email`, `user_url`, `user_first_name`, `user_last_name`, `user_nickname` and `user_display_name`.

how can I show autofill text value in below one?

```
[text* company-name id:companyName placeholder "Company Name here"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either use a custom JavaScript to populate your field once the page has loaded, and localise the data for your script and the currently logged-in user using the WordPress function [wp_localize_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) an example of which can be found on [wordpress.stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/306744/52120).

Alternatively, you can use a plugin extension such as the [Smart Grid-layout extension for CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) which has a built-in functionality to do this for you with the following hook,

```
add_filter('cf7sg_prefill_form_fields', 'prefill_my_form',10,2);
function prefill_my_form($values, $cf7_key){
  //check if this is the correct form
  if('my-form' != $cf7_key) return $values;
  //return an array of field-name=>value pairs.
  //fields with multiple selections such as checkboxes and dropdown menu can take an array as a value.
  
  //fetch the company name for teh currently logged-in user...
  $company_name = ...
  return array(
    'company-name' => $company_name,
  );
}
```

you can also find an online [tutorial](https://youtu.be/zPPD5VBF78w) that covers this.